# IdHTTP.Post - No progress for me to display in a progressbar

Tags: delphi, http, progress-bar, http-post, indy

I am trying to display the progress of a POST call from my TIdHTTP component.

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTP1Work(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
  AWorkCount: Int64);
begin
ProgressBar1.Position := AWorkCount;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdHTTP1WorkBegin(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
  AWorkCountMax: Int64);
begin
Progressbar1.Max := AWorkCountMax;
end;
```

However when I debug this, I land 2 times on the `.Max = AWorkCountMax;` line, and the first time the value is 65, and the 2nd time the value is 0.

I know it might not be necessary, since it doesent take long, but all depending on how much data is being returned, it can take long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

begin

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPWorkBegin(Sender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
  const AWorkCountMax: Integer);
begin
   if AWorkMode = wmRead then 
   begin
      ProgressBar.Max := AWorkCountMax; 
      ProgressBar.Position := 0; 
   end;
end;
```

tranfert

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPWork(Sender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
  const AWorkCount: Integer);
begin
   if AWorkMode=wmRead then 
     ProgressBar.Position := AWorkCount;
end;
```

end

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPWorkEnd(Sender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode);
begin
  ProgressBar.Position := 0;
end;
```

Comment: Hmm, I think it is because it cannot determine the actual size, since the output is being dynamically created..

Comment: That is correct. `AWorkCountMax` is zero when Indy does not know ahead of time how much data is expected. In HTTP, that usually means the server is sending the reply data in chunks (the reply contains a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header). When `AWorkCountMax` is zero, you should use a different UI to display the actual value of `AWorkCount`, which is the total number of bytes transferred so far.

Comment: @Remy - By adding a header to my php script, it fixed it. :)